# Copy file on Remote server's locations sub-directories

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I have created a script to copy a local file on remote server
Remote location is C:\past and local file needs to copy in all sub-directories from c:\past.
(i.e. c:\past\1, c:\past\2, c:\past3, c:\past\4 etc. etc..)

```
    $PathFrom = "C:\ISO\ncis.exe" 
    $computers="192.168.42.117"
    foreach ($computer in $computers)
    {
     $folders = Get-ChildItem "C:\past" -Directory 
    }
   foreach ($folder in $folders.name) 
    {

     #copy-item _path $PathFrom -ToSession $TargetSession -Destination "C:\past\$folder" -Recurse -ComputerName $computers
     copy-item _path $PathFrom -ComputerName $computers -Destination "C:\past\$folder" -Recurse
      }
```

Getting below error

```
enter Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\past' because it does not 
exist.
At line:3 char:14
+   $folders = Get-ChildItem "C:\past" -Directory
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\past:String) [Get-
ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommandcode 
here
```

Comment: is the server a network resource, Can you reach it by doing \\192.168.42.117\ ... if not then, does the remote server have PS Remoting turned on? The error you are getting is because currently you arent looking on the remote server but on the local server your script is running on. The error means exactly what it says ....cant find the folder C:\Past

Comment: Yes, I can reach it by \\192.168.42.117\

Comment: have you tried to copy using \\192.168.42.117\c$\past  ..... can tyou reach that location?

Comment: Manually hitting on file explorer \\192.168.42.117\c$\past , It works, However no idea how to do it with script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you can get to it througn a UNC path this should do what your looking for...

```
$PathFrom = "C:\ISO\ncis.exe" 
$computers="192.168.42.117"
foreach ($computer in $computers){
     Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\C$\past" -Directory | %{ Copy-Item -path $PathFrom -Destination $_.Fullname }
}
```

Comment: Getting below error `Copy-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not
take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`

Comment: Thank you @ArcSet, It works. Does it over-right existing file?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($folder in $folders.fullname)
```

Use Fullname instead of name.

This doesn't make sense, it is getting directory from local machine.

```
foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
 $folders = Get-ChildItem "C:\past" -Directory 
}
```

Copy-Item doesn't have -ComputerName Parameter

```
copy-item _path $PathFrom -ComputerName $computers
```

Check Examples
[Microsoft Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Yes, This where I stuck. C:\past is remote directory (i.e. on 192.168.42.117)